# Trouble with Javafx imports

Tags: javafx, package

After trying to run my import on my Jgrasp at home with different solutions.. I can't seem to find the problem.. I currently have JDK 8 installed.. This program runs fine on my school's computer.. I don't know what the problem might be, everytime I try to run the program it says packages does not exist..
[package does not exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3Ugm.png)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add the JavaFX library to the build path though I have never used JGrasp and I don't know how to do it there or if typically any imports such as that should be done automatically.

In Eclipse you would right-click on your project root and go to -> Build Path -> Add libraries... and in there you have the option to add the JavaFX SDK.

I hope that I could at least be of some help in maybe pointing you towards what could potentially could be causing the problem.